# Calculate or bound infimum

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, inequality

Let $a_1, \ldots, a_n \in\mathbb R$ and nonnegative let $b\geq1$ and $c\in [0,1]$.

Calculate or bound from above
$$
\inf \left\{d>0: \sum_{i=1}^n \ln \left((1-c)+c\left|1+\frac{a_i}{d}\right|^b\leq b      \right)\right\}.
$$

Thank you.

Comment: One can bound from above this infimum by $$\inf\left\{d>0: n \ln (2c)+\frac{b}{d}\sum_{i=1}^na_i\leq b\right\}$$. But now I am confused about the calculation of the infimum...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$
\inf \left\{d>0: \sum_{i=1}^n \ln \left((1-c)+c\left|1+\frac{a_i}{d}\right|^b\leq b      \right)\right\}\leq \inf \left\{d>0: n \ln(2c)+\sum_{i=1}^n\ln(\exp(b{a_i}/{d}))\leq b \right\}\leq \inf \left\{d>0: n \ln(2c)+\frac bd\sum_{i=1}^n{a_i}\leq b \right\}=n\ln(2c).
$$